# Getting NullInjectorError when trying to use AngularFireDatabase with Firebase Realtime Database in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

i am use
@angular/core: "^16.0.0",
@angular/fire: "7.6.1",
and want to get data from realtime Database firebase

access-lavel.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AccessLavelService {
constructor( private db: AngularFireDatabase ) {}

    getAccessLavel() {
        console.log( this.db.list('/g-access-lavel').snapshotChanges()  );
    }

}
```

I expect the data to be returned in getAccessLavel

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUw2u.png)

Comment: Did you call AngularFireModule.initializeApp(yourConfig) ?
See https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase#10 and https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase#9

Answer (score 0):

you need to import your modules before it you get can the values. Depending on if you have app.module or you do application bootstrap (standalone component) you still need to import the same way

import

```
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

add to providers:

```
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
```

you can follow their documentation on their gitup page https://github.com/angular/angularfire

though i will admit their documentation is not great nor up-to-date after they upgraded to firebase v9 / angular/fire v7+ where it became modular approach.